# Parsing feed with SimpleRSS in Rails, numeric codes appear, can't encode them properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, character-encoding, rss

I am using the SimpleRSS gem to parse a WordPress RSS feed. The only problem is that many characters in that feed are encoded using numeric codes, e.g.

```
&#8217;
```

instead of

```
'
```

#### Files

*rss_helper.rb*

```
module RssHelper
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'simple-rss'
  require 'open-uri'

  def rss
    rss = SimpleRSS.parse open('http://example.com/feed/')
  end
end
```

*show.html.slim*

```
...
-rss.entries.each do |entry|
  =entry.title
```

With the entry.title, I have tried:

```
=entry.title.encode("UTF-8")

=entry.title.encode(Encoding::UTF_8, :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => '')
```

Neither has worked. I found a lot of resources regarding the iconv gem, but from what I understand it is deprecated now.

I also attempted using the `.force_encoding` method instead of `.encoding`, but no matter what I choose it always displays that numeric code directly from the feed.

How do I force it to render the proper character?

EDIT: Here is my final helper using the gem suggested by the selected answer, included here so anyone who views this can see what I did.

*rss_helper.rb*

```
def decode(string) 
  coder = HTMLEntities.new 
  return coder.decode(string) 
end
```

*show.html.slim*

```
...
decode(entry.title)
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run it through [HTMLEntities](http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/).

```
HTMLEntities.new.decode(rss_feed_content)
```

This'll translate the entity-encoded characters into their literal equivalents.

Comment: I added that gem, then added this to my helper:

      def decode(string)
        coder = HTMLEntities.new
        return coder.decode(string)
      end

And it worked! I was able to call decode(entry.title) from the view! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Life saver... Thanks. Tip: Install the gem 'htmlentities' first